# editable table submit data to spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc

i am passing html data to spring controller. i tried lot of example but i cant find solution.

HTML FORM

```
<form:form action="addexternal" method="POST">
<table id="externalmicrometer">
   <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>data</td><td>data21</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>data1</td><td>data22</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>data2</td><td>data23</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

in this table adding dynamic rows. i am new at spring mvc. please help me to create controller

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="externalmicrometer">
   <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>data</td><td>data21</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>data1</td><td>data22</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>data2</td><td>data23</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The above code will not submit values to the server.

If you want to submit values to the server you have to make input fields like below.

```
<input type="text" name="data" value="3" />
```

name of the input field should be the same which your server is expecting in POJO or request parameter.